# I am getting issue while finding route from google api, it shows ,This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key

Tags: ios

```
 func getPolylineRoute(from source: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to destination: CLLocationCoordinate2D){

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

//        let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(source.latitude),\(source.longitude)&destination=\(destination.latitude),\(destination.longitude)&mode=driving&key=AIzaSyArY93s9tjsijSlVlH9jZ4OhavX5szM4Xw")!

        let service = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json"
        let originLat = source.latitude
        let originLong = source.longitude
        let destLat = destination.latitude
        let destLong = destination.longitude
        let urlString = "\(service)?origin=\(originLat),\(originLong)&destination=\(destLat),\(destLong)&mode=driving&units=metric&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyArY93s9tjsijSlVlH9jZ4OhavX5szM4Xw"
        let url  = URL(string: urlString)

//        let url = URL(string: "\("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json")?origin=\("28.7041"),\("77.1025")&destination=\(destination.latitude),\(destination.longitude)&sensor=true&key=\("AIzaSyDKuHYchwvdCjPRYF11VyNqA9xQA-18JH0")")!


        let task = session.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
          //      self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            }
            else {
                do {
                    if let json : [String:Any] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]{
                        print(json)
                        guard let routes = json["routes"] as? NSArray else {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                              //  self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                            }
                            return
                        }
                        if (routes.count > 0) {
                            let overview_polyline = routes[0] as? NSDictionary
                            let dictPolyline = overview_polyline?["overview_polyline"] as? NSDictionary
                            let points = dictPolyline?.object(forKey: "points") as? String
                            self.showPath(polyStr: points!)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                               // self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

                                let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: source, coordinate: destination)
                                let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, with: UIEdgeInsetsMake(170, 30, 30, 30))
                                self.mapView!.moveCamera(update)
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                              //  self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print("error in JSONSerialization")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       // self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }

    func showPath(polyStr :String){
        let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: polyStr)
        let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
        polyline.strokeWidth = 3.0
        polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        polyline.map = mapView // Your map view
    }
```

Comment: Google API keys can have restrictions set to ensure they are only used with a specific app bundle identifier. Go to your Google console, and check if your restrictions are set correctly for the API key. See the [bottom of this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/get-api-key) for instructions

Comment: The issue seems to be with the API key or API key settings. Check if both are correct and valid.

Answer (score 0):

Login to https://console.developers.google.com with your credentails.

Go to the `Credentials` tab in the left panel.

Click on `API Key` to open its settings.

Select needful `APIs` like shown below.

[image]

Comment: Yeah this problem is now resolve by your help. Thank you so much for your help.